# Optional Chaining - Function.prototype.apply was called on undefined, which is an undefined and not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, v8, optional-chaining

> [Using optional chaining with function calls causes the expression to automatically return undefined instead of throwing an exception if the method isn't found.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#optional_chaining_with_function_calls)

**Note: The code is using [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), not [`rest parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).**

```
const fn1 = undefined
const args = []
const fn2 = () => {}
const fn3 = () => {}

console.log(fn1?.(...args, fn2, fn3))
```

Error:

```
console.log(fn1?.(...args, fn2, fn3))
                                ^
TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on undefined, which is an undefined and not a function
```

Comment: The problem appears only when `...args` appears anywhere else other than the end in the function call. Weird.

Comment: It's weird that we get this error. Normally, you'ed get a "fn1 is not a function" error. This error shows up even when not using optional chaining.

Compare:

`(() => {
({test: undefined}).test(...([]))
})() // Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)}.test is not a function
`
vs 

`(() => {
({test: undefined}).test(...([]), 1)
})() // Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on undefined, which is a undefined and not a function
`

Comment: Looks like issue with chromium browsers, runs fine in Mozilla Firefox

Comment: This is definitely a bug - their experimental implementation of the optional chaining does not work with how they transpile calls with spread syntax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out to be a V8 bug, I've submitted it [there](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=11558), hopefully, it'll be fixed soon.

Update: [it has been fixed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=11558#c9).

Answer (score -4):

There are a couple rules to follow with ...rest arguments.

One of those rules is that the ...rest argument can only be the last argument.

```
foo(...one, ...wrong, ...wrong)
foo(...wrong, bad, bad)
foo(ok, ok, ...correct)
```

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Comment: But the question is using spread, not rest. And spread parameters can come anywhere, any number of times